# How to get outer html from python playwright locator object?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I could not find any method that returns outer html from python playwright  `page.locator(selector, **kwargs)`.
Am I missing something?
`locator.inner_html(**kwargs)` do exists. However, I am trying to use pandas.read_html and it fails on table locator inner html as it trips table tag.

What I'm currently doing is using bs4 to parse page.content().
something like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content(), 'lxml')
df = pd.read_html(str(soup.select('table.selector')))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `outer_html` out of the box. But it's not hard to implement it:

```
locator.evaluate("el => el.outerHTML")
```

Comment: could be an idea to add an out of the box way. I instictively tried await locator.content(), which bugged but your solution works perfectly. tx a lot